# Xcode 6 Copy Line/Cut Line keybindings

Tags: xcode

I recently have started development for Swift with XCode 6. I've used Sublime Text 3 for the last couple years, and more recently have fallen in love GitHub's Atom Editor. My biggest frustration so far with XCode is the lack of a copy/cut line tool.

In the text editors I've used copy/cut commands will copy/cut the whole line if no selection is made.

So far the only alternative I have found is the following:

```
Ctrl + A - Move cursor to the beginning of a line
Shift + ↓ - Select the line
Ctrl + C - Copy Selection
```

This works, however I'm wondering if anyone has figured out an elegant way to wrap these up into one powerful copy/cut line tool

On a side note, I am also missing the move line up/down shortcuts which are also very useful.

Note: a solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834096/how-do-i-create-a-delete-line-keyboard-shortcut-in-xcode-5-the-xcode-3-solution) no longer works in Xcode 6.

Comment: Have a look in the Xcode keybindings. Move line up and down is built in.

Comment: Glad to see that move line is built in, but I'm still not finding a copy/cut line. Thanks ^1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. From the terminal cd into / to get to the MacHD and then go into applications,otherwise you won't get all of the applications in the list.
2. open the 
   `file /Applications/XcodeBeta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` with sudo privileges (be sure to use the correct app-directory for the version of Xcode you are using---for Xcode 6.3 beta mine was Xcode-Beta.app). You can use `open .` in the terminal when you get to the desired location in finder
3. Now add the following section:

   `<key>My Custom Commands</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Cut Current Line</key>
       <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
       <key>Copy Current Line</key>
       <string>selectLine:, copy:</string>
   </dict>`

Restart XCode and in the keybindings section you should be able search for cut current line and copy current line and set custom keybindings to them. The format of creating commands is actually pretty simple and intuitive.

Comment: Just a sidenote: This does **not** allow to use `command` + `x`/`c` for the new `Cut Current Line`/`Copy Current Line` functionality **and** the normal `cut`/`copy` functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> On a side note, I am also missing the move line up/down shortcuts
>   which are also very useful.

Preferences->Key Bindings
Move line up:   option+command+[
Move line down: option+command+]