# XCode: comment out code in javascript file

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I normally comment and uncomment code with XCode using this command:
`(command+slash)`

This works just fine for swift file, but it does NOT work for javascript files. Is there way I can configure XCode to do this for all files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to extend the standard comment out command to Javascript as well, sorry :-(

Having said that, you could try adding a custom shortcut following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12678985/819340). (But might be tricky to completely reproduce the native *comment out* behavior.)

Comment: That's weird - I closed down Xcode and reopened it and now it totally works!