# Xcode 9.0(9A235) Delete Line shortcut does not take effect

Tags: xcode

Delete Line（Key Bindings-Deletions-Delete Line） is a very useful shortcut, but when I update my xcode to 9.0(9A235) it does not take effect. Why?

[image: Key Bindings]

Comment: Also doesn't work _Duplicate (Edit Menu)_ and _Jump to Next Counterpart_

Comment: I meet the same problem, do you find any solutions?

Comment: @Chen No,but I use BetterTouchTool instead.

Comment: I found a solution for this ,see:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868495/2585537, It work for me with version 9A235

Comment: It is work for me,thank you!But there is another question,it can not delete multiple line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple fixed KeyBindings in new [**Xcode** 9.1 beta](https://download.developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.1_beta/Xcode_9.1_beta.xip).

Now it works in a stable version of [**Xcode** 9.1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)