# Multiple-line cursor movements in XCode

Tags: xcode, key-bindings

I'd like to map a key to move the cursor in the XCode up by ten lines.  Of course, I want another one to move down too.  The key mapping would ideally be something like 'Control-Alt-P'.

Is there a way to achieve this in XCode without resorting to Automator?

---

Ashley has the answer below, the formatting was a little different as the property list is in XML format.

In summary, added an entry in the following format to the 'text' section of *.pbxkeys in ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Key Bindings/:

```
    <key>^~p</key>
    <array>
        <string>moveUp:</string>
        <string>moveUp:</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476953/delete-line-hot-key/477961#477961) and use a `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file, except use `moveUp:` and `moveDown:` as your selectors.

Your particular dictionary entry would look something like this:

```
{
    "^~P" = (
        "moveUp:",
        "moveUp:",
        "moveUp:",
        ... however many times ...
        "moveUp:",
    );
}
```

I have since learned that if you have customized your keybindings through Xcode already you should instead add the same dictionary entry to your `.pbxkeys` file under the `text` dictionary section.

Comment: Note this does not work in XCode4, and trying the same trick doesn't seem to work in the saved keyboard settings...

Comment: @Kendall, you ought to [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14419687/798527). If still interested, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  Always interested in new ways to tweak XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder for the impatient who didn't read all the way to the end of oldbeamer's question and are also looking to use .pbxkeys instead of .dict:

If you are wanting to add multi-action keybindings to your pbxkeys file, the XML formatting goes like this:

```
    <key>...</key>
    <array>
            <string>action1:</string>
            <string>action2:</string>
            <string>etc:</string>
    </array>
```

You can edit the .pbxkeys directly using a text editor to add custom multi-action keybindings this way.