# Multiple-line cursor movements in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

The same question [has been asked for Xcode 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/780048/404279)
But the solution there is said to not work with Xcode4. And no new solution is available there.

How to get a key-binding to move the curser up/down about 10 lines in Xcode 4 ?

Comment: If anybody knows for sure that there is no way then it would be great to have this as answer to be able to close this.

Comment: Robo, given that today is your question's anniversary, I'd like to point out that I know (for sure) that there _is_ a way. See the answer below. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eureka! Inspired by the [answer on line duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-4-duplicate-line), this is how you empower Xcode 4 with multiple-line movement:

1. Go to the folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources`
2. Open `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist`.
3. Add a new dictionary `Customized` and two new command (say, `Move Down 10` and `Move Up 10`) keys as the screenshot below:
   [image: Editing the plist]
4. Restart Xcode and go to Preferences - Key Bindings, search for your command.
5. Set a key combination for both commands:
   [image: Key Bindings]
6. Free at last from the shackles of the `Jump To` shortcut. Enjoy it!

---

### Bonus: system-wide multiple-line movement

Unleash the cursor outside Xcode following with these steps:

1. Go to the folder `~/Library/KeyBindings`
2. Open `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.
3. Enter the following. Customize as appropriate.

   > {
   >
   > "^~n"       = ("moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:", "moveUp:");
   >   "^~p"       = ("moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:", "moveDown:");
   >
   > }
4. Logout & Login

---

All of the above works on 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.5.1.

Comment: Be careful doing this one. Somehow I managed to mess up my plist doing it this way, which caused xcode to crash on launching. I fixed it and now it works great, but if I didn't know how to go into emacs and mess with the XML I would have been in trouble. (Though I suppose if I wasn't used to emacs I wouldn't be here, now would I?)

Comment: To keep scroll position: moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is impossible.
Answering myself to be able to close.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing [courteous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224849/multiple-line-cursor-movements-in-xcode-4/14419687#14419687), I added two more commands:

`Move Up 10 Extending Selection`, with the value `moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:`

and `Move Down 10 Extending Selection`, with the value `moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:`

[image: IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist screenshot]

then assigned the shortcut in XCode:

[image]