# What Xcode keyboard shortcuts do you use regularly?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

What Xcode keyboard shortcuts do you use regularly?

I am a huge believer in using the keyboard as much as possible (its much faster that way), and I was hoping others could share some of the Xcode shortcuts they use.

Comment: A question upvoted 43 times is not constructive?

Comment: How could this solicit anything but a list of commands?

Comment: I put together a PDF of popular keyboard shortcuts: http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/9/25/14-xcode-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet-pdf

Comment: I am surprised that none of the answers include [ctrl+6] for searching method or mark in the current file.

Comment: Eurgh it annoys me so much how useful threads get closed by the SO police...

Comment: For Xcode 9.3, go to answer given by Rein rPavi for all keyboard shortcuts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828262/is-there-a-go-to-file-in-xcode

Comment: See Link by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html) itself. My favorites are `Command-Shift-F` = Find in Workspace & `Command-Option-C` which will open the changes I've made & with less significance `Command-"` = Jump to Previous Issue, . Also note you can go and switch/change shortcuts. 99% of all operations can be configured to the shortcut you like. You can **replace/change** existing shortcuts to something else. Just go to Xcode >> behaviors >> key bindings

Answer (score 253):

I find the shortcuts to open & close various areas of the screen must useful.

[image: shortcuts]

Comment: Searched for this image in third time, finally saved, it's great. Always forget filters.

Comment: @DanSkeel Thank you.  Quick note on the navigator filter - I used to frequently use cmd-option-j to filter then navigate to source files.  However now I find the open quickly command better (cmd-shift-O , type a few chars, return)

Comment: If you want to focus on search field of `Search Navigator` you can press `Command + 3` and then hit `Command + Option + j`

Comment: A nice addition would be `^(1-6)` for the UI elements above the main editing area. You can easily navigate to `Recent Files`, `Callers`, and the `Method list`. Note that you can start typing after any one of those. (**Very** useful with `Control-6`.)

Comment: Does anyone know how to assign multiple Shortcuts to one action in the Xcode preferences? Some actions are pre-defined with multiple shortcuts, but I couldn't figure out how to, e.g. assign both PageUp and the default one for "Switch to next Counterpart".

Comment: @runroll that's very useful, thanks! I And noting that you can type into those is great. It's not clear from any UI indications that typing works, but it does. #noComplaints

Comment: What button is used to access the main editor? I can see that a key is cmmd, I don't know what the other is. I tried shift,option, arrows, enter, delete. Still not sure...

Comment: @Honey - ⏎ is the return key.  cmd-enter will get rid of any split view and just show the main editor.

Comment: @Robert correct. Yet it won't bring the cursor the maid editor. How can I do that?

Comment: Nobody mention cmd + ctrl + left/right arrow. its navigating forward and backward

Comment: After I hit `cmmd + 0` I want to just use the arrow keys to go up and down from the current selected file....is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 138):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> opens the "Open quickly" dialog, where you can quickly find and open files that contain the text you enter.

Comment: Changed to Cmd-Shift+o in Xcode 4

Comment: Changed to CTRL-i in Xcode 4.5

Comment: Still Cmd-Shift+o in my Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Appears to be CMD-Shift-o in Xcode 5 also.

Comment: this works on AppCode too. Also, you can do this in Atom, but you need this in your keymap file `  'shift-cmd-o': 'fuzzy-finder:toggle-file-finder'
`

Comment: Best shortcut of XCode period

Answer (score 61):

**Updated for newer versions:**

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Switches between corresponding .h / .m files or as [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html) own documentation, it means *Jump to Counterpart*

Comment: If you're on a .m file, it switches to the corresponding .h file, and vice versa.

Comment: It's Control+Cmd+Up/Down on my version of Xcode (4.5.2)

Comment: It's Control+CMD+Up/Down on Xcode 5.1

Comment: In Apple keyboard Control key called as Option.

Comment: Not a keyboard shortcut, but you can do the same with a three finger up/down gesture if you hava a trackpad.

Comment: too boring, I create my own shourcut with ctrl+tab, eclipse like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476953/xcode-delete-line-hot-key/26670057#26670057

Comment: @ArunPratap not correct. Option is option or alt, control is control

Comment: ctrl + cmd + rightArrow / leftArrow.. navigates to where you were before.  Its among the most beautiful shortcuts.

Answer (score 47):

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Reveals the current file in the project navigator. Very useful if you use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to jump to a definition as Xcode won't automatically reveal the containing file in the navigator.

Comment: love it! is super useful!

Answer (score 42):

<kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment out the current line, or multiple lines if they're highlighted.

Comes in handy for quick commenting and uncommenting while experimenting with code.

Comment: cmd + control + / too

Comment: Except uncomment doesn't bloody work half of the time.....

Comment: Uncommenting only does not work when your selection contains one or more lines that are not already commented.

Answer (score 27):

Re-indent. It's in `Edit > Format > Re-Indent` and there's no shortcut by default (I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>). It's a godsend.

Comment: There's also "Indent Selection", Control I.

Comment: There is a default keyboard shortcut added now (Xcode 4) for Re-Indent. Use Control + I. And the item has been moved under Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent.

Comment: Also highlight some code, and press `Command` + `[` or `]` to indent your selection.

Comment: Minor clarification, it's "Control +  letter i" I got crazy trying to use | lol

Comment: Happy News,
I have developed a xCode plugin which Indent the source file when saving :-) 
https://github.com/ThilinaHewagama/AutoIndentWithSave

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> Search in the File

<kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> Search & Replace in the File

<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> Search in the whole project

<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd>  <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> Search & Replace in the whole project

Notice the pattern for easy memorizing.

Comment: After Search in Project, once the results are in the Navigator, how can you iterate through them without having to use the mouse? (I hate having to click on each result)

Comment: Additionally, you can use Cmd + E to put the current selection in find (in file), and Cmd + G to select/jump to the next occurrence (Cmd + Shift + G moves backwards). Works great for quick replaces too (Alternating Cmd + G and Cmd + V). Personally I also mapped Cmd + Option + E to find selection in project, for consistency with the above.

Comment: @tothemario You can hit command-option-G to move to each project-level search result. shift-command-option-G will move back through each result.

Comment: @tothemario currently it's `Cmmd + Control + G` for next & `Cmmd + Control + Shift + G` for previous. If you want the key combination then go to Preferences >> Key Bindings >> search for 'Find Next in Workspace' & Find Previous in Workspace'

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> - Switch between header and implementation files.

Comment: You're making me cry!!! I didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
(Move focus to any section of the editor)

Comment: What does this actually help us with?

Comment: @Esqarrouth This shortcut can move the cursor from the assistant editor to the main editor, for example.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd>  + <kbd>j</kbd>

Highlight a keyword (method name) and jump to its definition. Also works for variables, #defines, etc.

Comment: Cmd + click on the symbol also works the same way.

Comment: Add Option to the above shortcut to open the definition in your assistant editor.

Answer (score 7):

Some of my favorite shortcuts are not keyboard shortcuts at all, but multitouch gestures. All Macbooks from early 2008 onward, and I would imagine desktops with a Magic Mouse or Magic Trackpad, support three-finger-swipe up and down to switch between the header and implementation, and three-finger-swipe left and right to navigate within the file history.

Comment: This doesnt work on my 2013 iMac with magic mouse, FYI, would be nice though!

Comment: I use 3 finger left and right, but having up and down is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Y</kbd> for the console.

Comment: I think you mean Command-Shift-Y. That's what it is in Xcode 4.4.1.

Comment: Yes, totally. Maybe it was Control back in Xcode 3 but it may also by a typo I made :)

Comment: @arlomedia Using the shortcut *only* opens the console, but doesn't move your cursor to there. Is there anyway that I can make the cursor move up to there?

Comment: @Honey command+Shift+C

Comment: @HaiFengKao thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

I find a cheat sheet next to the computer is the best way to pick up useful shortcuts. [Cocoa Samurai](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/02/complete-xcode-keyboard-shortcut-list.html) has a good one.

Answer (score 4):

### Key Bindings to XCode Actions

Create your own keyboard shortcuts using the **Text Key Bindings tab** of the **Key Bindings preference pane**. A time-saver all its own. Just lookup your favourite actions and add/edit shortcuts!

Another thread you may find useful is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago/1856308#1856308).

Answer (score 3):

Just the basic emacs navigation. Feels so right.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot live without three finger vertical swipe to switch between interface and implementation file. If you miss that in xcode-4/Lion, make sure to follow the following instructions:

http://geeksinkilts.com/?p=67

Comment: alternatively, (for those looking for a keyboard shortcut) ctrl+cmd+up toggles between them, too

Comment: Yeah, and much less of a hassle - wonder why you would want to move your hand to the trackpad when it's just a keyboard shortcut away..??

Comment: If your hand is already on the trackpad, it's a nice option to have.