# Is there a [Go to file...]?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In modern IDEs, there is a keyboard shortcut to open a file by typing its name without putting your hand on the mouse.  For example:

- Eclipse: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>|<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> Open Resource
- IntelliJ: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>|<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> -> Open File

Is there a `Go to file` or `Open file` shortcut in Xcode?

Answer (score 751, accepted):

Since Xcode 4 it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: In key bindings the name of this action is "Open Quickly..."

Answer (score 54):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is now the shortcut to find a file quickly and open it in Xcode 4

Answer (score 41):

Its not quite the same, but this might interest you:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Opens the project navigator and highlights the search bar, ready to type.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
Just opens the project navigator.

Comment: Cmd-Shift-J will do more than just open the project navigator. It'll do that and select the file that's open in the editing area. To Just open the project navigator, use Cmd-1 (or Cmd-2, Cmd-3 to open other navigators), or Cmd-0 to close them all.

Comment: Actually Cmd-Alt-J will will open whichever navigator was open last and highlight the search bar.

Answer (score 22):

*Updated to Xcode* `9.3`

**This is the quick guide for all the Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts:**

- Comment/ Un-comment code: <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Undo: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Redo: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Shift Right or Left: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> | <kbd>]</kbd>
- Indent: <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- Navigate to the beginning or end of line: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>
- Navigate word by word left or right of line: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>
- Bring up possible auto-completion choices: <kbd>esc</kbd>
- Jump To definition: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Click
- Put a breakpoint to a line: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>
- Move line up or down: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> | <kbd>]</kbd>
- Find in File: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Find & Replace in File: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Find in Project: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Find & Replace in Project: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- New Tab: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Next Tab: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>
- Previous Tab: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>
- Open Quickly: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Move Focus to Editor: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Navigate to Next File in Recently  Visited: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
- Navigate to Previous File in Recently Visited: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- Show present file in Editor: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Fold/ Unfold code: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>
- Fold/ Unfold all methods/functions: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>
- Fold/ Unfold all multiple line comments: <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> | <kbd>→</kbd>
- Font Size Increase/Decrease: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> | <kbd>-</kbd>
- Go to line number: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- Show Assistant Editor: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>
- Hide Assistant Editor: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↩</kbd>
- Toggle Completions: <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
- Edit All in Scope: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- Show / Hide Navigator: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- Switch Tabs: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>8</kbd>
- When clicking a File in Navigator open in
- Assistant Editor: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + Click

  - New Window: Double click
  - Decide where to open: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + Click
- Toggle Debug Area: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Next Issue: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>’</kbd>
- Previous Issue: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>”</kbd>
- Toggle Breakpoints: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Clear Console: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Show / Hide Utilities: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- Switch Tabs Utilities: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>
- Build: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Run: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Stop: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- Analyze: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Test: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Clean: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Help for Clicked Symbol: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + click
- Documentation for clicked Symbol: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + Double click
- Show Documentation: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- Documentation for Selection: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Move Focus to Filter in Navigator: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Move Focus to Filter in Utilities: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

File → Open Quickly...

You can assign a shortcut to it in Preferences → Key Bindings. The default should be <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

(If you have a `#include`/`#import`, you can place the text cursor on it and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill the file name automatically.)

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you hold down Command and click on the name of a class, Xcode will jump you to that class' implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to jump to specific line in specific file.
Then

First:
Command + Shift + o

Then type
CustomView:60

Means in file CustomView line number 60.